# OpenLayers 4 webmapcontext

Tags: openlayers-3

In one of my projects i want to use OL-4.6.5 instead of OL-2. But one key feature that we are using is the OpelLayers.Format.WMC().

Is this functionallity available in OL-4.6.5.

Regards
Magnus

Comment: Refer to OpenLayers doc and API to check if `OpelLayers.Format.WMC` exists. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/

Answer (score 0):

It is not, and it probably will never be, but you should be able to use JSONIX with ogc-schemas for this.